# Python User Interface

Tags: python, qt, user-interface

I want to make a user interface using python but i want it to be as beautiful as I can make elements in html and css. What do you offer ?!?
I've reached to Tinker and QT but I don't know if I can beautify them

Comment: Have a look at kivy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python offers the pyqt module. I recommend using pyqt4. If you want to have a beautiful interface, you could design it in Qt Designer and import it and create event handlers, etc. in the program.
You could install it [here](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download).

Once you install it you could design the interface in Qt Designer, save it as an ui file, and then import your ui file in the python program like this:

```
from pyqt4 import QtGui, uic
import sys
form_class = uic.loadUiType("your_file.ui")[0] 
class MainWindow(form_class, QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #here go all your event handlers, btn handlers, etc.

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = MainWindow(None)
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```